# WAMP server wont allow access to PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I'm trying to set up `PHP` on my laptop and I'm using the `WAMPP` server but when I try and go onto the `PHPMyAdmin` bit, it shows

> You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

How would I get round this?

And on a side note, I'm trying to link `MySQL workbench` with `PHP` and I don't know how as I want to get a little website running on my laptop but when I go to register a new member, I get

> Could not execute query

**EDIT**
In the `MySQL log` it shows the following

```
160518 16:11:56 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160518 16:11:56  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160518 16:11:56  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file .\ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
160518 16:11:56  InnoDB: Setting file .\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
160518 16:11:57  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...   
160518 16:11:57  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
160518 16:11:59  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 0
160518 16:11:59 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160518 16:11:59 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160518 16:11:59 [ERROR] Aborting

160518 16:11:59  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160518 16:12:01  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160518 16:12:01 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160518 16:34:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160518 16:34:02  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160518 16:34:02  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160518 16:34:02  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160518 16:34:02  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160518 16:34:02 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160518 16:34:02 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160518 16:34:02 [ERROR] Aborting

160518 16:34:03  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160518 16:34:04  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160518 16:34:04 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160518 16:54:31 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160518 16:54:31  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160518 16:54:31  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160518 16:54:32  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160518 16:54:32  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160518 16:54:32 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160518 16:54:32 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160518 16:54:32 [ERROR] Aborting

160518 16:54:32  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160518 16:54:33  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160518 16:54:33 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160518 17:48:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160518 17:48:21  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160518 17:48:21  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160518 17:48:21  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160518 17:48:22  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160518 17:48:22 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160518 17:48:22 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160518 17:48:22 [ERROR] Aborting

160518 17:48:22  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160518 17:48:23  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160518 17:48:23 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519  8:42:25 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519  8:42:25  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519  8:42:25  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519  8:42:26  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519  8:42:27  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519  8:42:27 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519  8:42:27 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519  8:42:27 [ERROR] Aborting

160519  8:42:27  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519  8:42:28  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519  8:42:28 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519  9:48:56 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519  9:48:56  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519  9:48:56  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519  9:48:56  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519  9:48:56  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:48:56 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519  9:48:56 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519  9:48:56 [ERROR] Aborting

160519  9:48:56  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519  9:48:57  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:48:57 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519  9:50:35 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519  9:50:35  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519  9:50:35  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519  9:50:35  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519  9:50:35  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:50:35 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519  9:50:35 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519  9:50:35 [ERROR] Aborting

160519  9:50:35  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519  9:50:37  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:50:37 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519  9:51:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519  9:51:03  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519  9:51:03  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519  9:51:03  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519  9:51:04  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:51:04 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519  9:51:04 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519  9:51:04 [ERROR] Aborting

160519  9:51:04  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519  9:51:05  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:51:05 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519  9:51:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519  9:51:15  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519  9:51:15  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519  9:51:15  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519  9:51:15  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:51:15 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519  9:51:15 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519  9:51:15 [ERROR] Aborting

160519  9:51:15  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519  9:51:16  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:51:16 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519  9:51:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519  9:51:36  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519  9:51:36  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519  9:51:36  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519  9:51:36  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:51:36 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519  9:51:36 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519  9:51:36 [ERROR] Aborting

160519  9:51:37  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519  9:51:37  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:51:37 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519  9:51:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519  9:51:41  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519  9:51:41  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519  9:51:41  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519  9:51:41  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:51:42 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519  9:51:42 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519  9:51:42 [ERROR] Aborting

160519  9:51:42  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519  9:51:43  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:51:43 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519  9:51:51 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519  9:51:51  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519  9:51:51  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519  9:51:51  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519  9:51:51  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:51:52 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519  9:51:52 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519  9:51:52 [ERROR] Aborting

160519  9:51:52  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519  9:51:53  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519  9:51:53 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519 10:12:25 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519 10:12:25  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519 10:12:25  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519 10:12:25  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519 10:12:25  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519 10:12:26 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519 10:12:26 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519 10:12:26 [ERROR] Aborting

160519 10:12:26  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519 10:12:27  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519 10:12:27 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519 10:12:31 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519 10:12:31  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519 10:12:31  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519 10:12:31  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519 10:12:32  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519 10:12:32 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519 10:12:32 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519 10:12:32 [ERROR] Aborting

160519 10:12:32  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519 10:12:33  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519 10:12:33 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519 10:12:38 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519 10:12:38  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519 10:12:38  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519 10:12:38  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519 10:12:39  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519 10:12:39 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519 10:12:39 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519 10:12:39 [ERROR] Aborting

160519 10:12:39  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519 10:12:40  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519 10:12:40 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519 10:12:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519 10:12:54  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519 10:12:54  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519 10:12:54  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519 10:12:54  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519 10:12:54 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519 10:12:54 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519 10:12:54 [ERROR] Aborting

160519 10:12:54  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519 10:12:56  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519 10:12:56 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

160519 10:13:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160519 10:13:21  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160519 10:13:21  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160519 10:13:21  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160519 10:13:21  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
160519 10:13:21 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160519 10:13:21 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160519 10:13:21 [ERROR] Aborting

160519 10:13:21  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160519 10:13:22  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160519 10:13:22 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: What version of WAMPServer did you install? What colour is the `wampmanager` icon in the system tray? Have you amended anything after the initial install?

Comment: Oh and Mysql Workbench has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have version 3.0.4 and it's orange, I haven't touched anything since the initial install

Comment: If its orange then one of the services, either Apache or MYSQL has not started. It should be green. **Which service is not started**

Comment: @RiggsFolly by the looks of it, it's the MySQL service, but when I click on `Start/Resume Service` nothing happens

Comment: Look at the mysql error log `left click wampmanager->MYSQL->Error log` if that shows you nothing then look at the `System Event Viewer` as MYSQL writes there before it opens its own log file

Comment: @RiggsFolly For clarity, the `Error log` is the same as `MySQL log`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'll add it into the question as there seems to be over 200 lines

Comment: Ah, when you installed MYSQL Workbench you also installed another MYSQL Server. Uninstall MYSQL Workbench, ensuring you also uninstall the other MYSQL Server. Then pick the Workbench that is just the Workbench tool and does not come with its own MYSQL ServerI Instance. Or maybe there is an option on the install of Workbench where you specify that you Do or DONOT want an instance of MYSQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 2 MYSQL Servers running.

When you installed MYSQL Workbench it has also installed another MYSQL Server. Both a re using port 3306. One MySQL Server instance is enough for anybody.

The MYSQL Server that came with Workbench is set to Automatically start on boot but WAMPServer only starts MYSQL Server when you start WAMPServer. So the one in WAMPServer is saying someone else has grabbed port 3306, I cannot start.

You only need one MYSQL Server to run 100's of databases, so I suggest you uninstall the MYSQL Server that came with WorkBench.

It may be easier to uninstall WorkBench completely. And then reinstall it, but without the MYSQL Server instance that comes with it.